# How do I make a slider return to the original position once the user releases it? Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, expression-blend, blend

I want to make a slider that acts as a button.  When the user slides it to the left, it returns to the original position on the right once the user releases the mouse button

Comment: Charles Petzold did a series of MSDN articles on customizing the slider control a while back.  I would check those out with a view towards mining any gems.

Comment: Let me guess.  You're trying to make a pinball game in WPF?  :)  Anyway, enjoy Petzold!

Comment: nice guess, but its for a novel way to do a certain action which I can't speak about :( but yes its akin to a pinball machine.  Any ideas?  I checked out Petzold, but couldn't find anything on this specific issue.  I emailed him though, hopefully he'll help, and I sent him the link to this question so as to resolve it for the community

Comment: did u try setting slider.value=0 on LostMouseCapture event?